# Simple derivation in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a question about Prolog.

I want to obtain a result like this in Prolog :

[image]

What i have not clear is : since CanFly(Superman) must be a term, in this case a function. Is is possible to achieve this derivation ?

Comment: `CanFly(Superman)` is not a valid Prolog term, and predicates are not functions.

Comment: So is not possible to represent a FOL (or prolog program) like the one of my post ?Instead uf you tell me it's possible, than i try to create a prolog program, and i'll show you

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could write a predicate, `knows_can_fly/2` in Prolog which would represent this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but a tweak is needed. Lois knows Clark Kent can fly if she knows Superman can fly and that Clark Kent is the secret identity of Superman. In Prolog saying `superman = clarckent` isn't possible, they're not the same thing. More accurately they're two names for the same being, so instead I'm using `aka`, for "also known as":

```
% Knowledge base, what Lois knows
knows(lois, can_fly(superman)).
knows(lois, aka(clark_kent, superman)).

% Rule: How Lois knows Clark Kent can fly
knows(lois, can_fly(clark_kent)) :-
    knows(lois, aka(clark_kent, superman)),
    knows(lois, can_fly(superman)).
```

Then you can write queries like:

```
?- knows(lois, can_fly(clark_kent)).
true.

?- knows(lois, can_fly(X)).
X = superman ;
X = clark_kent.
```